# "ORA-00984: column not allowed here" when inserting with select statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to insert some data into a table. One field I would like to get from another table, so I'm using select statement inside. This is the code:

```
INSERT INTO t.table1 ( 
  id, 
  id_t2, 
  date_of_change 
) 
VALUES ( 
  t.table1_seq.nextval, 
  SELECT s.id_id_t2 from t.table2 s where s.something='something', 
  TO_DATE('02/05/2017 13:43:34','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
)
```

Although select statement is always returning only 1 field (1 row), I presume this is why I'm getting the error.
How can I write INSERT statement with SELECT statement for just 1 field? Can it be done? If not, is there any other solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: There is an extra closing brace `)` at the end of select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate your whole `insert` statement into the form of

```
insert into table1 (fields)
select fields from table2
```

This will allow you to specify in your `select` some values from the source table and some constant values. Your resulting query would be

```
INSERT INTO t.table1 ( 
  id, 
  id_t2, 
  date_of_change 
) 
SELECT  t.table1_seq.nextval,
        s.id_id_t2,
        TO_DATE('02/05/2017 13:43:34','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM    t.table2 s
WHERE   s.something='something'
```